# How to transform pivot table to analyze single level of multiset column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a large amount of data, which I need to validate, of roughly the following simplified form:

```
program;param0;param1;param2;param3;param4;param5;WCET
bench1;P1;2;0;0;OFF;ALG1;23835
bench1;P1;4;4;0;OFF;ALG2;11520
bench2;P3;4;3;2;OFF;ALG1;2480450
bench2;P3;4;3;2;BB;ALG1;2480620
bench3;P2;6;2;2;BB;ALG3;2290
bench3;P2;4;4;0;OFF;ALG4;2490
```

I have aggregated it all into a pivot table using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def process_test_data():
    raw = pd.read_csv("omitted", sep=";")

    print("* benchmarks aggregated ")
    benchmarks_aggregated = pd.pivot_table(raw,
                                       values=['WCET'],
                                       index=['program'],
                                       columns=['param0', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4', 'param5', ],
                                       aggfunc={'WCET': [min, max]})
    print(benchmarks_aggregated)
```

This gives me the following output.

```
              WCET                        ...                                 
               max                        ...        min                      
param0          P1                        ...         P3                      
param1           2          4             ...          6                      
param2           0          3             ...          2                      
param3           0          0             ...          2                      
param4         OFF         BB             ...        OFF                      
param5        ALG1       ALG1       ALG2  ...       ALG3       ALG4       ALG5
program                                   ...                                 
bench1     23835.0   13460.0*   13610.0*  ...     8085.0     8280.0    10015.0
bench2   7439895.0  3777375.0  3682345.0  ...  2480085.0  2480350.0  3182175.0
bench3      6480.0     4050.0     4160.0  ...     2220.0     2340.0     3050.0
```

However, for further sanity checks I need a transformed representation, where I can compare the ALG[X] values for every distinct parameter set. For example, I need to know if the max WCET for ALG2 is always larger than that of ALG1, while all the other parameters are the same (Concrete example marked with *).

How can I transform my table so that I get the following structure? I tried unstacking and transforming, but that didn't give me the right sets of row and column indices. I am sure there is a way. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

```
* WCETmaxTable
           ALG1     ALG2     ALG3
0          ...      ...      ...
1          ...      ...      ...
...
n          ...      ...      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of completeness I post the solution I found later on:

This first transforms the row index to columns, then transposes all column levels to index, then unstacks only `param5` again back to columns. To simplify the multiindex like in the example in the question, replaces the index with a range counter afterwards.

```
    benchmarks_aggregated = benchmarks_aggregated.unstack().T.unstack(level='param5')
    benchmarks_aggregated.index = range(len(benchmarks_aggregated))
```